# jQuery to check Android native browser or Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome

I used this script and many different ways. Still it output both Samsung native browser and Chrome as "Android Chrome".

How can I solve this issue?

```
var nua = navigator.userAgent;
var is_android = ((nua.indexOf('Mozilla/5.0') > -1 && nua.indexOf('Android ') > -1 &&     nua.indexOf('AppleWebKit') > -1) && !(nua.indexOf('Chrome') > -1));

var chrome_android = (nua.indexOf('Chrome') > -1);

if(is_android){
    $('.nativeBrowser').show();
    $('.otherMobBrowser').hide();
    alert("Android Native")
}
else if(chrome_android){
    $('.nativeBrowser').hide();
    $('.otherMobBrowser').show();
    alert("Android Chrome")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
var is_native_android = ((ua.indexOf('Mozilla/5.0') > -1 && ua.indexOf('Android ') > -1 && ua.indexOf('AppleWebKit') > -1) && (ua.indexOf('Version') > -1));

if(is_native_android){
    $('.nativeBrowser').show();
    $('.otherMobBrowser').hide();
}
else {
    $('.nativeBrowser').hide();
    $('.otherMobBrowser').show();
}
```